# cygwin connection refused for port 22

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I have installed cygwin in windows 7 but i get the following error

```
    $ ssh localhost
    ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: Hey Jan5 did you ever figure this out? Were you trying to install Hadoop on Windows?

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem but I ran this on the CYGWIN command line and it worked  :

```
 ~ : net start sshd
```

After that I executed the command `ssh -v localhost` and the error message didn't show up. Hope that this helps !.

Comment: `name for the service is invalid` is the error. So I need a `sshd`. Where?

Answer (score 5):

If you are facing this problem in Windows XP follow these steps to open port for ssh:

1. Go to windows firewall of security section in control panel
2. Exceptions->add port
3. Give port name as ssh and number as  22.
4. Select option TCP
5. Click on Ok

This will help you open ssh from cygwin

For local application development like hadoop on windows please change the scope `localhost /ip address` in the custom list.

Comment: Hi @Jothi, can you explain what you mean by "please change the scope 'localhost /ip address' in the custom list"? Where do I find this and what do I change it to? I am getting the same error as the OP even after installing `ssh-host-config`. I can't seem to start the windows service

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use port 23 or ask your host provider for the ssh port. Some host providers change the ssh port.

```
ssh user@yoursite.com -p 23
```

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin doesn't install an SSH server by default, although you can set up sshd if you want. By default, however, there's nothing to ssh to.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/) and then do a

```
 $~ net start sshd    
 $~ ssh localhost
```